# Visual Studio 2010 Can't use full functionality

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to open project as a web site(File->Open->Web Site->File System) from the server which is in the same domain as my workstation. I can see the full project in the Solution Explorer. I can open any file and update it. But it seems that VS2010 doesn't see any dll's, namespaces etc. There is any code references or code hints. Can't use .sln file, because of a lot off errors when I'm trying to open it (Ektron CMS). Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Is there a .prj file to open instead?

Comment: No, only .sln file and App_Folders, cs and aspx files

Comment: Have you tried running Visual Studio as administrator before opening via the File System, just a guess but could be a permissions problem.

Comment: Actually I didn't run VS as admin but I gave full rights on remote wwwroot folder. But you're main idea was absolutely correct.

Comment: Great - I've added it as answer for future users then. I'm happy it's working for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio may need administrator permissions to fully access the the source code. You could try opening Visual Studio as administrator or perhaps giving full access rights on the remote wwwroot folder.